# VBA .Find to use for Setting Ranges

Tags: vba, find, range

I am very new to Excel, but one thing that seems to be super powerful is using .Find to name ranges. Unfortunately, I'm only seen people use it with message boxes and things like that afterwards. What I'm trying to do is a bit more complicated.

I am trying to find a cell named 'State' somewhere in the 'rec' worksheet. After it finds it I need to set a range from one cell above the 'State' cell up six cells.

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim rec As Worksheet

Set rec = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rec")

Dim State As String

Dim MoveHeadersUp As Range

State = "State"


Set MoveHeadersUp = rec.Rows.Find(What:=State, LookIn:=xlValues, _
Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If MoveHeadersUp Is Nothing Then

MsgBox "Uh-Oh. Column A is missing a header titled 'State'. You better create one!"

Else
```

???????

```
 End Sub
```

Comment: You keep using the term "name" but Find is used to find cells based on *content*, so maybe you're not referring to named ranges at all?  You can use Offset() to refer to a range relative to a starting point (in this case the result from Find(). )

Comment: Hi Tim, nice hearing from you again. I posted this over on Mr. Excel and a user helped me with the last line. What I was looking for was this: Dim SpaceAbove as Range

     Set SpaceAbove =         Range(MoveHeadersUp.Offset(IIf(MoveHeadersUp.Row > 1, -1, 0), 0).Address, MoveHeadersUp.Offset(IIf(MoveHeadersUp.Row > 6, -6,     (MoveHeadersUp.Row - 1) * -1), 0).Address)


     debug.print SpaceAbove.Address

Answer (score 0):

```
Else

'''THIS IS THE ANSWER
Set spaceabove = Range(MoveHeadersUp.Offset(IIf(MoveHeadersUp.Row > 1, -1, 0), 0).Address, MoveHeadersUp.Offset(IIf(MoveHeadersUp.Row > 6, -6, (MoveHeadersUp.Row - 1) * -1), 0).Address)

Debug.Print spaceabove.Address

End If
'''I was trying to delete the rows 
spaceabove.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim SpaceAbove as Range 

If MoveHeadersUp.Row>6 Then
    Set SpaceAbove = MoveHeadersUp.Offset(-6,0).Resize(6,1)
    Debug.print SpaceAbove.Address
Else
    msgbox "Can't move up 6 rows from 'MoveHeadersUp' !"
End If
```

Comment: Tim! That's great! Thanks for that. That works great as well. I tried upvoting it, but I don't have '15' reputation yet, so it won't allow me to do so. Do you have any advice for me to begin learning more about VBA? I just ordered the book 'VBA for Dummies' and will next order Power Programming 2013. The principles of VBA still seem to be eluding me (perhaps those books will help), though I've only been using VBA a little over a month. Thanks again!

Comment: Power programming (Excel 95!) was the one I started with - that definitely gavbe me a good foundation for VBA.